# How to adjust vertical labels on this Line Chart?

Tags: highcharts

I tried almost every setting but couldn't get these vertical dates labels "outside" of [**this graph**](http://jsfiddle.net/R4JvP/11/) under the xAxis line. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely didn't try *every* settings :) You can give the labels a [y-offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.y)

```
        labels: {
            rotation: 270,
            y:40                
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/5JXBR/

Comment: Thanks a lot Jugal. I thought y-offset can only be applied on y-Axis. Appreciate it a lot!